# stop form from submitting (tried e.preventDefault() after $.post but it stops form from submitting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this in javascript

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {  
        $('#message_line').text("");    
        if(validate_fields_on_submit()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }   
       // e.preventDefault();
        var params = $('form').serialize(); 
        $.post('check_duplicate.php', params, function(responseText) {
            submitHandler(responseText);
        });
//      e.preventDefault();
//return false;
    });
    function submitHandler(response) {
        $('#message_line').text("");    
        response = $.trim(response);
        if(response == "" && response.indexOf("<") <= -1)
            $('#registration').submit();
        else if(response.indexOf("<") == 0) {
            var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
            $('#message_line').text("Some error occured, please try after some time.");  
            $("#message_line").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
            return false;  
        } else {   
            var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
            var arr = response.split(',');
            arr.pop();
            arr.toString();
            $('#message_line').text("'" + name + "' already exists, Please try different username");  
            $("#regusername").focus();
            return false;
        }                                    
        $('#busy_wait').css('display','none'); 
    }
```

HTML CODE

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        include("db/helper_functions.php");
        if(validate_fields()) {
            if(!check_duplicate($_POST["regusername"])) {
                $count = insert_record($_POST["fname"],$_POST["lname"],$_POST["email"],$_POST["regusername"],$_POST["regpassword"]);
                if($count > 0) {
                    include("includes/confirmation.php");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $error = "Sorry registration failed, please try again.";
                }
            }
            else {
                $error = "Username already exists, please try different username.";
            }
        }
    }
    $page_title = "Registration";
    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
        include('includes/header_authorized.html');
    else
        include('includes/header.html');

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="regform">
        <form  name="registration" id="registration" method="post" action="registration.php">
            <p><span class="req">* required field.</span></p>                      
            <ul>
                <li><label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="textboxborder" id="fname" name="fname" size="20" maxlength="25" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname'];?>"/>
                    <span class="error" id="errfname">*<?php if(isset($errfname)) echo $errfname;?></span>
                </li>
                <li><label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="textboxborder" id="lname" name="lname" size="20" maxlength="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lname'])) echo $_POST['lname'];?>"/>
                    <span class="error" id ="errlname">*<?php if(isset($errlname)) echo $errlname;?></span>
                </li> 
                <li><label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="textboxborder" name="email" id="email" size="40" maxlength="50" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];?>"/> 
                    <span class="error" id="erremail">*<?php if(isset($erremail)) echo $erremail;?></span>  
                </li>
                <li><label for="regusername">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="regusername" id="regusername" size="20" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['regusername'])) echo $_POST['regusername'];?>"/> 
                    <span class="error" id="errregusername">*<?php if(isset($errregusername)) echo $errregusername;?></span> 
                </li>
                <li><label for="regpassword">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="regpassword" id="regpassword" size="20" maxlength="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['regpassword'])) echo $_POST['regpassword'];?>"/> 
                    <span class="error" id="errregpassword">*<?php if(isset($errregpassword)) echo $errregpassword;?></span> 
                </li>
                <li><label for="regconpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="regconpassword" id="regconpassword" size="20" maxlength="15"/> 
                    <span class="error" id="errregconpassword">*<?php if(isset($errregconpassword)) echo $errregconpassword;?></span> 
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="message_line">&nbsp;<?php if(isset($error)) echo $error;?></div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div> 
        </form>  
        <img src="images/loading.gif" id="busy_wait" alt="busy wait icon" />  
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If in submit handler control goes in else if or else block form submission does not stop,I tried `return false;` and I tried using   `e.preventDefault();` at different places before ajax call and after but that stops form submission even after validation success and successful return from check_duplicate.php
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a submit button with id=submit, I would

1. rename the button since calling anything submit is poor practice since you need to actually submit the form programatically.
2. move the handler to the form submit event - I personally NEVER attach a handler to a submit button
3. I assume you do NOT want to submit if the validation returns false

Like this

```
$('#registration').on('submit', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message_line').text("");    
    if(!validate_fields_on_submit()) { // I assume you meant NOT
      return;
    }   
    var params = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.post('check_duplicate.php', params, function(responseText) {
        submitHandler(responseText);
    });
});
```

the post can be written

```
$.post('check_duplicate.php', params, submitHandler);
```

UPDATE Here is the complete script - NOTE IMPERATIVE to rename anything name=submit or id=submit to something else

```
$(function() {
  $('#registration').on('submit', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message_line').text("");    
    if(!validate_fields_on_submit()) { // I assume you meant NOT
      return;
    }   
    $('#busy_wait').show(); 
    $.post('check_duplicate.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
      response = $.trim(response);
     if (response == "" && response.indexOf("<") <= -1) {
        $('#registration').submit(); // actually submit the form
      }
      else if(response.indexOf("<") == 0) {
        var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
        $('#message_line').text("Some error occured, please try after some time.");  
        $("#message_line").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
      } else {   
        var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
        $('#message_line').text("'" + name + "' already exists, Please try different username");  
        $("#regusername").focus();
      }                                    
      $('#busy_wait').hide();
  });
});
```

---

Update3:

```
$(function() {
  $('#registration').on('submit', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message_line').text("");    
    if(!validate_fields_on_submit()) { // I assume you meant NOT
      return;
    }   
    $('#busy_wait').show(); 
    var $thisForm=$(this); // save for later
    var params = $thisForm.serialize(); 
    $.post('check_duplicate.php', params, function(response) {
      response = $.trim(response);
     if (response == "" && response.indexOf("<") <= -1) {
        // actually submit the form
        $.post($thisForm.prop("action"), params, function(response) {
          if (response.indexOf("success") !=-1) {    
            $('#message_line').text(response);
          }
          else {
            $('#message_line').text("something went wrong");
          }
          $('#busy_wait').hide();
        });
     }
     else if(response.indexOf("<") == 0) {
        var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
        $('#message_line').text("Some error occured, please try after some time.");  
        $("#message_line").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
      } else {   
        var name = $('[name="regusername"]').val();
        $('#message_line').text("'" + name + "' already exists, Please try different username");  
        $("#regusername").focus();
      }                                    
      $('#busy_wait').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: So it is even more important you change the name of the submit button. I changed my script to point at the form ID you use. See the complete script at the end

Comment: Please show the HTML - it should not loop. A better way would be to POST the form action too using AJAX the way you post the check_duplicate

Comment: Which means? It works? You of course have to change "success" to something actually found in the page and you do not have to show the whole page

Comment: console.log the response to see what it shows. Also look in the console for other errors

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: It should not execute event handlers when called directly but if you do not want Ajax, add $("#registration").off('submit"); just before the submit

Comment: Not sure why this is not working, but I'm using your 3rd solution and reloading div with response, thank you for all the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent form submission the best method will be to return false on the onclick client event 
Eg

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

 return false;
```

})

Comment: instead of   e.preventDefault() use return false;

Comment: it stops form to submit even if it validates